# UIImageView in UICollectionView not drawing correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have an app with a screen that is divided into four equal cells. Each cell has an image, label, and color. I'm trying to add the images in, but for some reason, only the image in the first cell works.

It looks like this now: [image]

Here is my code:
In ViewController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    colorArray += [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.yellow]

    pictureArray += [UIImage(named: "budget")!, UIImage(named: "journey")!,
                     UIImage(named: "learn")!, UIImage(named: "settings")!]

    titleArray += ["Budget", "Journey", "Learn", "Settings"]
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 4
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell


    // Set cell properties
    cell.backgroundColor = colorArray[indexPath.row]

    let imageview:UIImageView=UIImageView(image: pictureArray[indexPath.row])
    let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    imageview.center = cell.center
    imageview.bounds = CGRect(origin: cell.bounds.origin, size: size)

    cell.contentView.addSubview(imageview)

    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

The labels and colors work fine, but for some reason, the image views seem to be off the screen. I have a feeling that my center/bounds restrictions are forcing the images off the screen, but I've tried many combinations, and none of them seem to work for me.

How should I do this?

Comment: It will be better if you use prototype cells. Have you tried to see the View Hierarchy?

Comment: Place some other image at the start of pictureArray and check whether that image is also drawn in first cell?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I created my own subclass of UICollectionViewCell with an IBOutlet for the image and the title and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the correct answer for who ever will google here. (And because it was solved an hour ago without anyone posting the answer)

The best practice is to subclass `UICollectionViewCell`, connect all the outlets (label, image etc.) and work with this class on the cells

Good luck to all

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked, after Yogesh Suthar's comment:

I subclassed UICollectionViewCell, connected the image and label:

```
class NavigationCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var navImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var navLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Then, in the ViewController, I did this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NavigationCollectionViewCell


    // Set cell properties
    cell.backgroundColor = colorArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.navImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.navLabel.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Set the size and position of the image and label in Main.storyboard!

Answer (score 0):

insert the desired view as a subclass and setup all constrains to cell.heightAchor and so on. this will fix the bug for some reason. It works if the subview is added to the cell as a subview but not as an attribute of the cell